# How to get products list in Shopware Plugin

Tags: shopware

I am having very hard time getting list of products to be displayed in the landing page using a plugin.
The documentation found insufficient in this regard.

I got stuck here:

```
$controller = $args->get('subject');
        $view = $controller->View();

        $view->addTemplateDir(
            __DIR__ . '/Views'
        );
```

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems you are just starting with plugin development in shopware. Maybe it helps if you take a look at the example plugins: https://github.com/shopware/devdocs/tree/master/exampleplugins/5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help you in the approach to the issue

```
//get current article Id
$articleId = $view->sArticle['articleID'];
$query = $this->container->get('dbal_connection')->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('s_articles.name')
  ->from('s_articles')
  ->where('s_articles.id = :id')
  ->setParameter('id', $articleId);
$single = $query->execute()->fetchColumn();
$view->assign('article_name', $single);
$view->assign('article_cat', '<a href="'.$view->sArticle['linkDetailsRewrited'].'">'.$view->sArticle['linkDetails'].'</a>' );


/**
 * Add template to the directory plugin
 */
$view->addTemplateDir($this->container->getParameter('gwen_cinema.plugin_dir') . '/Resources/Views');
```